# Laravel - Auth::check() returning false, but middleware auth not redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

So somehow i was managed to produce a situation where Auth::check() says that i'm not logged in, but middleware('auth') is still allowing acces to my class. The last thing i did was modify user data, but I did not log out, so im assuming Auth::check() is returning the wrong value. But why could it be so? My controller construct:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        print "yes";
    } else {
        print "no";
    };

    $this->middleware('auth');

}

public function index()
{
   print " index";
}
```

This prints out "no index". So Auth::check() return false, but index method is still raeched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is called before the middleware. Laravel allows you to provide controller middleware, so you push to the middleware stack from within a controllers constructor.

Any form of session interaction in the constructor of a controller will fail.